# Prototype: how to move selected options from one select to another?

Tags: html-select, prototypejs

Using prototype 1.6 how can I remove all selected options from one select and append them to another?  I guess I should add that when they show up in the target they should not be selected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, which involved just using "plain-jane" javascript to get the selected options and de-select them. This uses prototype 1.6 and works fine.

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Hello World</h2>

    <div style="border:solid 1px black">

        <select id="leftSelect" multiple="multiple" size="3">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>

        <span class="test">
            <button id="moveRightBtn">&gt;&gt;</button><br/>
            <button id="moveLeftBtn">&lt;&lt;</button>
        </span>

        <select id="rightSelect" multiple="multiple" size="3">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.observe("dom:loaded", function()
        {
            Event.observe("moveRightBtn", "click", function()
            {
                move($("leftSelect"), $("rightSelect"));
            });

            Event.observe("moveLeftBtn", "click",  function()
            {
                move($("rightSelect"), $("leftSelect"));
            });
        });

        function move(sourceSelect, targetSelect)
        {
        var options = sourceSelect.select("option");

        options.each(function(item)
        {
           if(item.selected)
           {
              item.selected = false;
              targetSelect.appendChild(item.remove());
           }
        });
        }

    </script>

</body>
```